# Unable to access Kubernetes cluster using the go client when CLOUDSDK_CONFIG is set

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I have a kubernetes cluster on GKE. Even after setting KUBECONFIG="/tmp/kubeconfigxvz" correctly, when I execute `kubectl get pods` the command fails with the following error

```
bash-4.3# kubectl get pods
Unable to connect to the server: error executing access token command 
"/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config config-helper --format=json": err=exit 
status 1 output= stderr=ERROR: (gcloud.config.config-helper) You do not 
currently have an active account selected.
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
different account:

  $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.
```

When I set the `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=/tmp/customdir` the command starts working.

How can I achieve the same with the go client?

=== UPDATE ===

When creating the go client I pass the correct file pointer to this function 
`clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *tmpKubeConfigFile)` where `tmpKubeConfigFile` points to `/tmp/kubeconfigxvz`.
But I think this is not sufficient, the go-client also needs some more information from the `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG` directory, I think it needs the session information or credentials or something.

Is it possible to pass this CLOUDSDK_CONFIG too when creating the go-client?

`BuildConfigFromFlags` that takes in input the pointer to kubeconfig file and returns a `config` object, which can be passed to `kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)` which creates the client. Is it possible or does there exists a similar function to pass the CLOUDSDK_CONFIG and returns a go-client or create a config?

Answer (score 2):

You basically need to create a `~/.kube/config` file to access your GKE cluster directly.

You can see [in this go client example](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/out-of-cluster-client-configuration/main.go#L38) that it's picking up the config from `~/.kube/config`

A GKE config would look something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: [REDACTED]
    server: https://x.x.x.x
  name: gke_project_us-central1-a_your-first-cluster-1
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: gke_project_us-central1-a_your-first-cluster-1
    user: gke_project_us-central1-a_your-first-cluster-1
  name: gke_project_us-central1-a_your-first-cluster-1
current-context: gke_project_us-central1-a_your-first-cluster-1
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: gke_project_us-central1-a_your-first-cluster-1
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
```

You would have to change the users section with something like:

```
- name: myuser
  user:
     token: [REDACTED]
```

The user is a service account with a token, if you want to add this user to manage everything in your cluster you can `ClusterRoleBind` it to an `admin` role.

For more information about `RBAC`, `ServiceAccounts`, `Roles`, `ClusterRoles`, and `Users` you can see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).

Btw, unfortunately, GKE doesn't give you access to the master node so you can't create certificate authentication because you don't have access to the `CA.key` file.